# Using pubnub in android

Tags: android, notifications, pubnub

Has anyone succeeded in using pubnub examples for android? I am working a senior project that uses it for interacting with raspberry pi remotely. The demo project works find but replacing the pub/sub key with my own causes unknownhostExecption. I have created GCM account and using the api key as the sender ID. My manifest is registered the appropriate permission as well. I have been stuck with for a while. but still unable to figure out the cause. 
 What do i need to do?

Answer (score 1):

I will start by linking to an Android PubNub project that was created to interact with a Raspberry Pi remotely. Take a look here https://github.com/GleasonK/PHue

> I have created GCM account and using the api key as the sender ID.

Are you trying to use GCM? If all you need is Pub/Sub you simply need your developer Pub and Sub keys. Unknown host might be because you are using the wrong keys. Visit the admin console and log in (https://admin.pubnub.com/). You should then see `Publish Key` and `Subscribe Key`. Those are the two you need to use when instantiating a `Pubnub` object in Android.

If your project actually requires GCM, PubNub does support that as well. [From the PN Blog](http://www.pubnub.com/blog/pubnub-now-supports-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-for-android/). If this is what you need me to elaborate on let me know and I would be glad to!